# How to detect change (1 or 0) on PORTC of Atmega8?

Tags: atmega

I have made PORTC.0,PORTC.1,PORTC.2,PORTC.3 as input and set it at high. The remaining pins are set as output and high. Thus all pins of PORTC are high.

Now what I want to check that whenever any pin of PORTC gets low (0), then my function  "setDirection()"should be called. For that I have written

```
if(~PINC)setDirection();
```

but ~PINC condition comes out to be always true, irrespective of any pin of PORTC is low or not.
Then I tried this code

```
if(!PINC)setDirection();
```

this condition never turns out to be true, either PORTC PIN is high or low.

Comment: While it has been answered how to check pin state correctly, its not clear what are you trying to achieve. What does setDirection() do exactly?

Comment: @Rev i was trying to detect that if any of the pin of port c gets low function "setDirection()" should be called which then checks which pin of port c is low and sets direction accordingly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((PINC & 0x0F) != 0x0F) setDirection();
```

This tests if any of the 4 bits are not high. The tests you tried require that ALL of the bits be low.